# The height of table columns dont stay as high as table column text

Tags: html, css

I have a table that consist of three columns and 4 rows, the top rows are the headings and the 3rd column has a rowspan that stretches accross 3 rows, according to different pages the number of rows may increase or decrease.

Now the problem I have and need to sort is that if the rowspan column 3 the longer the text gets row 2 column 2 should not stretch further than where the last text line, and all other column 2 and column 1 should align to the top. So the padding-bottom should not increase the longer the rowspan column gets

See fiddle below http://jsfiddle.net/gS87J/

code

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td width="25%">Line 1</td>
        <td width="25%">Line 2</td>
        <td>Line 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">Description 1</td>
        <td valign="top">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
            <br /><br />
The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</td>
        <td valign="top" rowspan="3">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce rutrum nunc at dolor elementum rhoncus. Morbi neque ipsum, sagittis quis condimentum commodo, laoreet nec lacus. Morbi eget dui in mi cursus vulputate. Nam ut porttitor sem. Nullam tincidunt posuere dui, sit amet porttitor tellus euismod ut. Morbi sollicitudin scelerisque nunc id aliquam. Suspendisse potenti. Donec ut diam ut massa dictum scelerisque. Sed justo nisi, scelerisque et aliquet nec, bibendum vitae massa. Quisque in mollis urna. In ut ultricies nisl, et scelerisque nisi. Aenean erat neque, blandit nec justo a, sodales gravida nisl. Aenean placerat urna ut est tincidunt laoreet.

Praesent sem ante, commodo eget mollis eget, mollis quis arcu. Nunc quis posuere nisi. Integer pretium enim ut mi dapibus porta. Aenean ac ipsum lacus. Nunc feugiat, augue tempus auctor dapibus, enim augue gravida massa, sed viverra orci nisi quis nisi. Vivamus sagittis mollis elit quis aliquam. Curabitur hendrerit est hendrerit elit dapibus vulputate. Ut at bibendum ipsum, eget convallis ligula. Sed vel pulvinar eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.

Praesent vel malesuada mauris. Aliquam dignissim rhoncus sapien, nec dictum lorem aliquet pretium. Nulla facilisis, mi quis commodo elementum, sapien sapien pellentesque nulla, ultricies ultricies quam dolor at sapien. Duis porttitor ligula ut orci ultricies, et vestibulum ante sollicitudin. Mauris vel felis dolor. Proin posuere lacus tortor, quis gravida nisl scelerisque eu. Vivamus porta interdum tempus. Phasellus justo enim, sagittis non diam eget, pretium semper orci. Nam lobortis posuere nunc. Nulla rutrum nibh ac tristique consectetur. Fusce ac justo metus.

Proin accumsan nibh in sem semper imperdiet. Sed a libero et justo suscipit eleifend id quis mi. Aenean eros sem, mattis ac tempus gravida, porttitor vel lectus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam nec magna tortor. Mauris congue consectetur augue rhoncus viverra. Maecenas sollicitudin enim et porta tincidunt. Nullam vel magna non turpis pretium pretium malesuada nec velit. Cras vel felis nec mi tincidunt rutrum semper sit amet orci. Suspendisse pellentesque elit nec nisi consectetur, a venenatis orci gravida. Pellentesque fermentum metus nec tortor varius, eu egestas mi sagittis.

Cras et ligula tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus vulputate turpis quis nibh faucibus rhoncus. Aliquam volutpat ut mauris in hendrerit. Proin eget ipsum iaculis, auctor est ac, ornare sem. Donec non scelerisque justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis suscipit interdum nunc vel pellentesque. Cras tincidunt odio sed nibh aliquam facilisis. Nullam id tincidunt elit. Ut ac tempus elit. Nam metus eros, sagittis sit amet sapien vel, bibendum pulvinar nisl.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce rutrum nunc at dolor elementum rhoncus. Morbi neque ipsum, sagittis quis condimentum commodo, laoreet nec lacus. Morbi eget dui in mi cursus vulputate. Nam ut porttitor sem. Nullam tincidunt posuere dui, sit amet porttitor tellus euismod ut. Morbi sollicitudin scelerisque nunc id aliquam. Suspendisse potenti. Donec ut diam ut massa dictum scelerisque. Sed justo nisi, scelerisque et aliquet nec, bibendum vitae massa. Quisque in mollis urna. In ut ultricies nisl, et scelerisque nisi. Aenean erat neque, blandit nec justo a, sodales gravida nisl. Aenean placerat urna ut est tincidunt laoreet.

Praesent sem ante, commodo eget mollis eget, mollis quis arcu. Nunc quis posuere nisi. Integer pretium enim ut mi dapibus porta. Aenean ac ipsum lacus. Nunc feugiat, augue tempus auctor dapibus, enim augue gravida massa, sed viverra orci nisi quis nisi. Vivamus sagittis mollis elit quis aliquam. Curabitur hendrerit est hendrerit elit dapibus vulputate. Ut at bibendum ipsum, eget convallis ligula. Sed vel pulvinar eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.

Praesent vel malesuada mauris. Aliquam dignissim rhoncus sapien, nec dictum lorem aliquet pretium. Nulla facilisis, mi quis commodo elementum, sapien sapien pellentesque nulla, ultricies ultricies quam dolor at sapien. Duis porttitor ligula ut orci ultricies, et vestibulum ante sollicitudin. Mauris vel felis dolor. Proin posuere lacus tortor, quis gravida nisl scelerisque eu. Vivamus porta interdum tempus. Phasellus justo enim, sagittis non diam eget, pretium semper orci. Nam lobortis posuere nunc. Nulla rutrum nibh ac tristique consectetur. Fusce ac justo metus.

Proin accumsan nibh in sem semper imperdiet. Sed a libero et justo suscipit eleifend id quis mi. Aenean eros sem, mattis ac tempus gravida, porttitor vel lectus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam nec magna tortor. Mauris congue consectetur augue rhoncus viverra. Maecenas sollicitudin enim et porta tincidunt. Nullam vel magna non turpis pretium pretium malesuada nec velit. Cras vel felis nec mi tincidunt rutrum semper sit amet orci. Suspendisse pellentesque elit nec nisi consectetur, a venenatis orci gravida. Pellentesque fermentum metus nec tortor varius, eu egestas mi sagittis.

Cras et ligula tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus vulputate turpis quis nibh faucibus rhoncus. Aliquam volutpat ut mauris in hendrerit. Proin eget ipsum iaculis, auctor est ac, ornare sem. Donec non scelerisque justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis suscipit interdum nunc vel pellentesque. Cras tincidunt odio sed nibh aliquam facilisis. Nullam id tincidunt elit. Ut ac tempus elit. Nam metus eros, sagittis sit amet sapien vel, bibendum pulvinar nisl.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce rutrum nunc at dolor elementum rhoncus. Morbi neque ipsum, sagittis quis condimentum commodo, laoreet nec lacus. Morbi eget dui in mi cursus vulputate. Nam ut porttitor sem. Nullam tincidunt posuere dui, sit amet porttitor tellus euismod ut. Morbi sollicitudin scelerisque nunc id aliquam. Suspendisse potenti. Donec ut diam ut massa dictum scelerisque. Sed justo nisi, scelerisque et aliquet nec, bibendum vitae massa. Quisque in mollis urna. In ut ultricies nisl, et scelerisque nisi. Aenean erat neque, blandit nec justo a, sodales gravida nisl. Aenean placerat urna ut est tincidunt laoreet.

Praesent sem ante, commodo eget mollis eget, mollis quis arcu. Nunc quis posuere nisi. Integer pretium enim ut mi dapibus porta. Aenean ac ipsum lacus. Nunc feugiat, augue tempus auctor dapibus, enim augue gravida massa, sed viverra orci nisi quis nisi. Vivamus sagittis mollis elit quis aliquam. Curabitur hendrerit est hendrerit elit dapibus vulputate. Ut at bibendum ipsum, eget convallis ligula. Sed vel pulvinar eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.

Praesent vel malesuada mauris. Aliquam dignissim rhoncus sapien, nec dictum lorem aliquet pretium. Nulla facilisis, mi quis commodo elementum, sapien sapien pellentesque nulla, ultricies ultricies quam dolor at sapien. Duis porttitor ligula ut orci ultricies, et vestibulum ante sollicitudin. Mauris vel felis dolor. Proin posuere lacus tortor, quis gravida nisl scelerisque eu. Vivamus porta interdum tempus. Phasellus justo enim, sagittis non diam eget, pretium semper orci. Nam lobortis posuere nunc. Nulla rutrum nibh ac tristique consectetur. Fusce ac justo metus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce rutrum nunc at dolor elementum rhoncus. Morbi neque ipsum, sagittis quis condimentum commodo, laoreet nec lacus. Morbi eget dui in mi cursus vulputate. Nam ut porttitor sem. Nullam tincidunt posuere dui, sit amet porttitor tellus euismod ut. Morbi sollicitudin scelerisque nunc id aliquam. Suspendisse potenti. Donec ut diam ut massa dictum scelerisque. Sed justo nisi, scelerisque et aliquet nec, bibendum vitae massa. Quisque in mollis urna. In ut ultricies nisl, et scelerisque nisi. Aenean erat neque, blandit nec justo a, sodales gravida nisl. Aenean placerat urna ut est tincidunt laoreet.

Praesent sem ante, commodo eget mollis eget, mollis quis arcu. Nunc quis posuere nisi. Integer pretium enim ut mi dapibus porta. Aenean ac ipsum lacus. Nunc feugiat, augue tempus auctor dapibus, enim augue gravida massa, sed viverra orci nisi quis nisi. Vivamus sagittis mollis elit quis aliquam. Curabitur hendrerit est hendrerit elit dapibus vulputate. Ut at bibendum ipsum, eget convallis ligula. Sed vel pulvinar eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.

Praesent vel malesuada mauris. Aliquam dignissim rhoncus sapien, nec dictum lorem aliquet pretium. Nulla facilisis, mi quis commodo elementum, sapien sapien pellentesque nulla, ultricies ultricies quam dolor at sapien. Duis porttitor ligula ut orci ultricies, et vestibulum ante sollicitudin. Mauris vel felis dolor. Proin posuere lacus tortor, quis gravida nisl scelerisque eu. Vivamus porta interdum tempus. Phasellus justo enim, sagittis non diam eget, pretium semper orci. Nam lobortis posuere nunc. Nulla rutrum nibh ac tristique consectetur. Fusce ac justo metus.

Proin accumsan nibh in sem semper imperdiet. Sed a libero et justo suscipit eleifend id quis mi. Aenean eros sem, mattis ac tempus gravida, porttitor vel lectus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam nec magna tortor. Mauris congue consectetur augue rhoncus viverra. Maecenas sollicitudin enim et porta tincidunt. Nullam vel magna non turpis pretium pretium malesuada nec velit. Cras vel felis nec mi tincidunt rutrum semper sit amet orci. Suspendisse pellentesque elit nec nisi consectetur, a venenatis orci gravida. Pellentesque fermentum metus nec tortor varius, eu egestas mi sagittis.

Cras et ligula tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus vulputate turpis quis nibh faucibus rhoncus. Aliquam volutpat ut mauris in hendrerit. Proin eget ipsum iaculis, auctor est ac, ornare sem. Donec non scelerisque justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis suscipit interdum nunc vel pellentesque. Cras tincidunt odio sed nibh aliquam facilisis. Nullam id tincidunt elit. Ut ac tempus elit. Nam metus eros, sagittis sit amet sapien vel, bibendum pulvinar nisl.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce rutrum nunc at dolor elementum rhoncus. Morbi neque ipsum, sagittis quis condimentum commodo, laoreet nec lacus. Morbi eget dui in mi cursus vulputate. Nam ut porttitor sem. Nullam tincidunt posuere dui, sit amet porttitor tellus euismod ut. Morbi sollicitudin scelerisque nunc id aliquam. Suspendisse potenti. Donec ut diam ut massa dictum scelerisque. Sed justo nisi, scelerisque et aliquet nec, bibendum vitae massa. Quisque in mollis urna. In ut ultricies nisl, et scelerisque nisi. Aenean erat neque, blandit nec justo a, sodales gravida nisl. Aenean placerat urna ut est tincidunt laoreet.

Praesent sem ante, commodo eget mollis eget, mollis quis arcu. Nunc quis posuere nisi. Integer pretium enim ut mi dapibus porta. Aenean ac ipsum lacus. Nunc feugiat, augue tempus auctor dapibus, enim augue gravida massa, sed viverra orci nisi quis nisi. Vivamus sagittis mollis elit quis aliquam. Curabitur hendrerit est hendrerit elit dapibus vulputate. Ut at bibendum ipsum, eget convallis ligula. Sed vel pulvinar eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.

Praesent vel malesuada mauris. Aliquam dignissim rhoncus sapien, nec dictum lorem aliquet pretium. Nulla facilisis, mi quis commodo elementum, sapien sapien pellentesque nulla, ultricies ultricies quam dolor at sapien. Duis porttitor ligula ut orci ultricies, et vestibulum ante sollicitudin. Mauris vel felis dolor. Proin posuere lacus tortor, quis gravida nisl scelerisque eu. Vivamus porta interdum tempus. Phasellus justo enim, sagittis non diam eget, pretium semper orci. Nam lobortis posuere nunc. Nulla rutrum nibh ac tristique consectetur. Fusce ac justo metus.

Proin accumsan nibh in sem semper imperdiet. Sed a libero et justo suscipit eleifend id quis mi. Aenean eros sem, mattis ac tempus gravida, porttitor vel lectus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam nec magna tortor. Mauris congue consectetur augue rhoncus viverra. Maecenas sollicitudin enim et porta tincidunt. Nullam vel magna non turpis pretium pretium malesuada nec velit. Cras vel felis nec mi tincidunt rutrum semper sit amet orci. Suspendisse pellentesque elit nec nisi consectetur, a venenatis orci gravida. Pellentesque fermentum metus nec tortor varius, eu egestas mi sagittis.

Cras et ligula tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus vulputate turpis quis nibh faucibus rhoncus. Aliquam volutpat ut mauris in hendrerit. Proin eget ipsum iaculis, auctor est ac, ornare sem. Donec non scelerisque justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis suscipit interdum nunc vel pellentesque. Cras tincidunt odio sed nibh aliquam facilisis. Nullam id tincidunt elit. Ut ac tempus elit. Nam metus eros, sagittis sit amet sapien vel, bibendum pulvinar nisl.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce rutrum nunc at dolor elementum rhoncus. Morbi neque ipsum, sagittis quis condimentum commodo, laoreet nec lacus. Morbi eget dui in mi cursus vulputate. Nam ut porttitor sem. Nullam tincidunt posuere dui, sit amet porttitor tellus euismod ut. Morbi sollicitudin scelerisque nunc id aliquam. Suspendisse potenti. Donec ut diam ut massa dictum scelerisque. Sed justo nisi, scelerisque et aliquet nec, bibendum vitae massa. Quisque in mollis urna. In ut ultricies nisl, et scelerisque nisi. Aenean erat neque, blandit nec justo a, sodales gravida nisl. Aenean placerat urna ut est tincidunt laoreet.

Praesent sem ante, commodo eget mollis eget, mollis quis arcu. Nunc quis posuere nisi. Integer pretium enim ut mi dapibus porta. Aenean ac ipsum lacus. Nunc feugiat, augue tempus auctor dapibus, enim augue gravida massa, sed viverra orci nisi quis nisi. Vivamus sagittis mollis elit quis aliquam. Curabitur hendrerit est hendrerit elit dapibus vulputate. Ut at bibendum ipsum, eget convallis ligula. Sed vel pulvinar eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.

Praesent vel malesuada mauris. Aliquam dignissim rhoncus sapien, nec dictum lorem aliquet pretium. Nulla facilisis, mi quis commodo elementum, sapien sapien pellentesque nulla, ultricies ultricies quam dolor at sapien. Duis porttitor ligula ut orci ultricies, et vestibulum ante sollicitudin. Mauris vel felis dolor. Proin posuere lacus tortor, quis gravida nisl scelerisque eu. Vivamus porta interdum tempus. Phasellus justo enim, sagittis non diam eget, pretium semper orci. Nam lobortis posuere nunc. Nulla rutrum nibh ac tristique consectetur. Fusce ac justo metus.

Proin accumsan nibh in sem semper imperdiet. Sed a libero et justo suscipit eleifend id quis mi. Aenean eros sem, mattis ac tempus gravida, porttitor vel lectus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam nec magna tortor. Mauris congue consectetur augue rhoncus viverra. Maecenas sollicitudin enim et porta tincidunt. Nullam vel magna non turpis pretium pretium malesuada nec velit. Cras vel felis nec mi tincidunt rutrum semper sit amet orci. Suspendisse pellentesque elit nec nisi consectetur, a venenatis orci gravida. Pellentesque fermentum metus nec tortor varius, eu egestas mi sagittis.

Cras et ligula tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus vulputate turpis quis nibh faucibus rhoncus. Aliquam volutpat ut mauris in hendrerit. Proin eget ipsum iaculis, auctor est ac, ornare sem. Donec non scelerisque justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis suscipit interdum nunc vel pellentesque. Cras tincidunt odio sed nibh aliquam facilisis. Nullam id tincidunt elit. Ut ac tempus elit. Nam metus eros, sagittis sit amet sapien vel, bibendum pulvinar nisl.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce rutrum nunc at dolor elementum rhoncus. Morbi neque ipsum, sagittis quis condimentum commodo, laoreet nec lacus. Morbi eget dui in mi cursus vulputate. Nam ut porttitor sem. Nullam tincidunt posuere dui, sit amet porttitor tellus euismod ut. Morbi sollicitudin scelerisque nunc id aliquam. Suspendisse potenti. Donec ut diam ut massa dictum scelerisque. Sed justo nisi, scelerisque et aliquet nec, bibendum vitae massa. Quisque in mollis urna. In ut ultricies nisl, et scelerisque nisi. Aenean erat neque, blandit nec justo a, sodales gravida nisl. Aenean placerat urna ut est tincidunt laoreet.

Praesent sem ante, commodo eget mollis eget, mollis quis arcu. Nunc quis posuere nisi. Integer pretium enim ut mi dapibus porta. Aenean ac ipsum lacus. Nunc feugiat, augue tempus auctor dapibus, enim augue gravida massa, sed viverra orci nisi quis nisi. Vivamus sagittis mollis elit quis aliquam. Curabitur hendrerit est hendrerit elit dapibus vulputate. Ut at bibendum ipsum, eget convallis ligula. Sed vel pulvinar eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.

Praesent vel malesuada mauris. Aliquam dignissim rhoncus sapien, nec dictum lorem aliquet pretium. Nulla facilisis, mi quis commodo elementum, sapien sapien pellentesque nulla, ultricies ultricies quam dolor at sapien. Duis porttitor ligula ut orci ultricies, et vestibulum ante sollicitudin. Mauris vel felis dolor. Proin posuere lacus tortor, quis gravida nisl scelerisque eu. Vivamus porta interdum tempus. Phasellus justo enim, sagittis non diam eget, pretium semper orci. Nam lobortis posuere nunc. Nulla rutrum nibh ac tristique consectetur. Fusce ac justo metus.

Proin accumsan nibh in sem semper imperdiet. Sed a libero et justo suscipit eleifend id quis mi. Aenean eros sem, mattis ac tempus gravida, porttitor vel lectus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam nec magna tortor. Mauris congue consectetur augue rhoncus viverra. Maecenas sollicitudin enim et porta tincidunt. Nullam vel magna non turpis pretium pretium malesuada nec velit. Cras vel felis nec mi tincidunt rutrum semper sit amet orci. Suspendisse pellentesque elit nec nisi consectetur, a venenatis orci gravida. Pellentesque fermentum metus nec tortor varius, eu egestas mi sagittis.

Cras et ligula tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus vulputate turpis quis nibh faucibus rhoncus. Aliquam volutpat ut mauris in hendrerit. Proin eget ipsum iaculis, auctor est ac, ornare sem. Donec non scelerisque justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis suscipit interdum nunc vel pellentesque. Cras tincidunt odio sed nibh aliquam facilisis. Nullam id tincidunt elit. Ut ac tempus elit. Nam metus eros, sagittis sit amet sapien vel, bibendum pulvinar nisl.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce rutrum nunc at dolor elementum rhoncus. Morbi neque ipsum, sagittis quis condimentum commodo, laoreet nec lacus. Morbi eget dui in mi cursus vulputate. Nam ut porttitor sem. Nullam tincidunt posuere dui, sit amet porttitor tellus euismod ut. Morbi sollicitudin scelerisque nunc id aliquam. Suspendisse potenti. Donec ut diam ut massa dictum scelerisque. Sed justo nisi, scelerisque et aliquet nec, bibendum vitae massa. Quisque in mollis urna. In ut ultricies nisl, et scelerisque nisi. Aenean erat neque, blandit nec justo a, sodales gravida nisl. Aenean placerat urna ut est tincidunt laoreet.

Praesent sem ante, commodo eget mollis eget, mollis quis arcu. Nunc quis posuere nisi. Integer pretium enim ut mi dapibus porta. Aenean ac ipsum lacus. Nunc feugiat, augue tempus auctor dapibus, enim augue gravida massa, sed viverra orci nisi quis nisi. Vivamus sagittis mollis elit quis aliquam. Curabitur hendrerit est hendrerit elit dapibus vulputate. Ut at bibendum ipsum, eget convallis ligula. Sed vel pulvinar eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.

Praesent vel malesuada mauris. Aliquam dignissim rhoncus sapien, nec dictum lorem aliquet pretium. Nulla facilisis, mi quis commodo elementum, sapien sapien pellentesque nulla, ultricies ultricies quam dolor at sapien. Duis porttitor ligula ut orci ultricies, et vestibulum ante sollicitudin. Mauris vel felis dolor. Proin posuere lacus tortor, quis gravida nisl scelerisque eu. Vivamus porta interdum tempus. Phasellus justo enim, sagittis non diam eget, pretium semper orci. Nam lobortis posuere nunc. Nulla rutrum nibh ac tristique consectetur. Fusce ac justo metus.

Proin accumsan nibh in sem semper imperdiet. Sed a libero et justo suscipit eleifend id quis mi. Aenean eros sem, mattis ac tempus gravida, porttitor vel lectus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam nec magna tortor. Mauris congue consectetur augue rhoncus viverra. Maecenas sollicitudin enim et porta tincidunt. Nullam vel magna non turpis pretium pretium malesuada nec velit. Cras vel felis nec mi tincidunt rutrum semper sit amet orci. Suspendisse pellentesque elit nec nisi consectetur, a venenatis orci gravida. Pellentesque fermentum metus nec tortor varius, eu egestas mi sagittis.

Cras et ligula tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus vulputate turpis quis nibh faucibus rhoncus. Aliquam volutpat ut mauris in hendrerit. Proin eget ipsum iaculis, auctor est ac, ornare sem. Donec non scelerisque justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis suscipit interdum nunc vel pellentesque. Cras tincidunt odio sed nibh aliquam facilisis. Nullam id tincidunt elit. Ut ac tempus elit. Nam metus eros, sagittis sit amet sapien vel, bibendum pulvinar nisl.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce rutrum nunc at dolor elementum rhoncus. Morbi neque ipsum, sagittis quis condimentum commodo, laoreet nec lacus. Morbi eget dui in mi cursus vulputate. Nam ut porttitor sem. Nullam tincidunt posuere dui, sit amet porttitor tellus euismod ut. Morbi sollicitudin scelerisque nunc id aliquam. Suspendisse potenti. Donec ut diam ut massa dictum scelerisque. Sed justo nisi, scelerisque et aliquet nec, bibendum vitae massa. Quisque in mollis urna. In ut ultricies nisl, et scelerisque nisi. Aenean erat neque, blandit nec justo a, sodales gravida nisl. Aenean placerat urna ut est tincidunt laoreet.

Praesent sem ante, commodo eget mollis eget, mollis quis arcu. Nunc quis posuere nisi. Integer pretium enim ut mi dapibus porta. Aenean ac ipsum lacus. Nunc feugiat, augue tempus auctor dapibus, enim augue gravida massa, sed viverra orci nisi quis nisi. Vivamus sagittis mollis elit quis aliquam. Curabitur hendrerit est hendrerit elit dapibus vulputate. Ut at bibendum ipsum, eget convallis ligula. Sed vel pulvinar eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.

Praesent vel malesuada mauris. Aliquam dignissim rhoncus sapien, nec dictum lorem aliquet pretium. Nulla facilisis, mi quis commodo elementum, sapien sapien pellentesque nulla, ultricies ultricies quam dolor at sapien. Duis porttitor ligula ut orci ultricies, et vestibulum ante sollicitudin. Mauris vel felis dolor. Proin posuere lacus tortor, quis gravida nisl scelerisque eu. Vivamus porta interdum tempus. Phasellus justo enim, sagittis non diam eget, pretium semper orci. Nam lobortis posuere nunc. Nulla rutrum nibh ac tristique consectetur. Fusce ac justo metus.

Proin accumsan nibh in sem semper imperdiet. Sed a libero et justo suscipit eleifend id quis mi. Aenean eros sem, mattis ac tempus gravida, porttitor vel lectus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam nec magna tortor. Mauris congue consectetur augue rhoncus viverra. Maecenas sollicitudin enim et porta tincidunt. Nullam vel magna non turpis pretium pretium malesuada nec velit. Cras vel felis nec mi tincidunt rutrum semper sit amet orci. Suspendisse pellentesque elit nec nisi consectetur, a venenatis orci gravida. Pellentesque fermentum metus nec tortor varius, eu egestas mi sagittis.

Cras et ligula tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus vulputate turpis quis nibh faucibus rhoncus. Aliquam volutpat ut mauris in hendrerit. Proin eget ipsum iaculis, auctor est ac, ornare sem. Donec non scelerisque justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis suscipit interdum nunc vel pellentesque. Cras tincidunt odio sed nibh aliquam facilisis. Nullam id tincidunt elit. Ut ac tempus elit. Nam metus eros, sagittis sit amet sapien vel, bibendum pulvinar nisl.
Proin accumsan nibh in sem semper imperdiet. Sed a libero et justo suscipit eleifend id quis mi. Aenean eros sem, mattis ac tempus gravida, porttitor vel lectus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam nec magna tortor. Mauris congue consectetur augue rhoncus viverra. Maecenas sollicitudin enim et porta tincidunt. Nullam vel magna non turpis pretium pretium malesuada nec velit. Cras vel felis nec mi tincidunt rutrum semper sit amet orci. Suspendisse pellentesque elit nec nisi consectetur, a venenatis orci gravida. Pellentesque fermentum metus nec tortor varius, eu egestas mi sagittis.

Cras et ligula tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus vulputate turpis quis nibh faucibus rhoncus. Aliquam volutpat ut mauris in hendrerit. Proin eget ipsum iaculis, auctor est ac, ornare sem. Donec non scelerisque justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis suscipit interdum nunc vel pellentesque. Cras tincidunt odio sed nibh aliquam facilisis. Nullam id tincidunt elit. Ut ac tempus elit. Nam metus eros, sagittis sit amet sapien vel, bibendum pulvinar nisl. </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td valign="top">Description 2</td>
            <td valign="top">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td valign="top">Description 3</td>
            <td valign="top">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried a couple of things and not sure how to not let the column stretch when it gets longer, I tried adding a fixed height but then the font goes over the border lines.

Any ideas on how to keep the height of the columns only as height as the text in the column and only let the last column stretch as far as the rowspan column

Screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: I've read your question a few times and still have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: Your problem is that you are using tables. Why not just use divs and do some research on div columns?

Comment: @j08691 - The problem is that the longer the rowspan column gets, the longer the other columns also get, I need to have the other columns only as high as the text. and let the last rows column stretch to the remaining height

Comment: @Cam - Divs would be ideal, but re-doing this would take some time which is not really there, so I thought maybe there is something one can do about it in the table

Comment: You could just set the borders to none. That way people cant see that it is a table. its cheating it a bit, but its better to do something right then wrong, everyones had to do a project over so I sympathize with you.

Comment: @Cam - Yes probably needs to be done over in divs, the problem is the client sees the gap and complains about it, the borders are off by default. It does not really look bad at all, but unfortunately the call is not mine, thank you for trying to help

Comment: Oh, by the way, people here are offended by your use of tables, but I was much more shocked to see that you are using `valign`. Come on, that was declared deprecated _over fourteen years ago!_

Comment: @MrLister - Thank you for the pointers, and I do apologize to everyone I might have offended. Will stop the use tables together with valign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```css
tr:not(:last-child) {height:1px;}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/gS87J/12/)

The trick is that tables adjust their heights to fit the content, so even if you set the height to something less, the row will still look right.

Works in Firefox, Chrome *and* Opera.

Comment: This solution works brilliantly for all browsers except IE, I'm on IE 11. Is there perhaps a workaround that it could work in IE?

Comment: @Roland No, sorry, I have experimented and IE really won't cooperate. IE handles `height` as `min-height` very strictly inside tables. So the only way to influence things is to give the last `tr` an explicit height the size you need. For instance, if the whole table is 100em high and the content of the top three `tr`s adds up to 30em, specify 70em for the height of the last one. But the calculation depend on the actual content, of course, so that is no universal solution. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the advise, I managed to get it working in IE 11 using JQuery to calculate the height of each row and then assigning the remaining height to the last row which seemed to have solved my problem for now

Comment: OK, glad you got it working. If you want, you can add that as an answer of your own.