# Adjacent Selector CSS with Height:Auto Css not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css

I have the following code which does not work in Internet Explorer 11 but works in Chrome and Firefox

```
tr {height:1px;}
tr + tr + tr + tr {height:auto}
```

The fiddle below shows exactly what it does, the whole description of what I'm trying to accomplish is listed in the following question: [The height of table columns dont stay as high as table column text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21438179/the-height-of-table-columns-dont-stay-as-high-as-table-column-text)

http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/gS87J/12/

I've played around with different doctypes and it just does not want to work

Comment: Are you sure it's the selector that's not working, and not the css itself? Have you tried applying any other css (such as border) to prove that it is / is not the selector?

Comment: @cale_b - When adding a background color to the table row it works

Comment: So that tells you that IE 11 does not like *height:auto;*, and that the adjacent selector **is working**.

Comment: @cale_b - Do you know about any work arounds for IE 11 that will work?

Comment: No workarounds, sorry. I've abandoned the use of tables for things like this, particularly the moment `rowspan` becomes required.  I've simply had too many issues creating cross-browser compliant markup that worked.

Comment: @cale_b - Thank you, yes that's quite a problem at the moment for this specific project. Maybe something can be done using Javascript.

Comment: on the first place , it is not a good idea to relay on styling `<tr>`, this element is not suppose to be seen, collapsing table or not, has effects on its layout, not cross-browser anyway and heights of table element cannot be fixed, the main specification of tables is to shrink/expand depending on its contents. You need to wrap td's / th's content in a container and fixed your heights to these container. you can , reset some displays value to table elements, but it won't layout as a table anymore.

Comment: @Roland did you solve the question you just deleted?

Comment: @meda - Yes, did solve it. I deleted the question because not to sure how to explain the answer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get this working using JavaScript by means of JQuery, I've calculated the total height of the table using JQuery and then getting the height of each row, by using the column content height of the column in the row with the highest height. I then took the total height of the column deducting the height of each row from the total excluding the last row and then assigned the remaining height to the last table row which then solved my problem.